# How to call a function ASA the app runs in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an application that do login with the help of firestore database and I want to do autologin so I made a boolean and set it to false in the database and made the login function set it to true as he or she sign in, so I want to check if the person have already signed in or not as the app runs, any ideas :) ?
here my code:

```
void getUserData() async {
    try {
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      firestoreInstance
          .collection("Students")
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
          loggedin = (value.data)['token'];
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use a boolean to check if the user is logged in or not. Firebase authentication already offers that. You can check inside the `initState`:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
      print(res);
      if (res != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: res.uid)),
        );
      }
      else
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Checks if there is a current user or not and navigates to the required page.

---

If you have different types of users, then you have to identify them in the database. So authenticate in firebase authentication, and use a `userType` field in the database:

```
  void registerToFb() {
    firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) {
      firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(result.user.uid).setData({
        "email": emailController.text,
        "name": nameController.text,
        "userType" : "Students"
      }).then((res) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(uid: result.user.uid)),
        );
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I did user login with the database not the authentication

Comment: and used your method

Comment: you are using `var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();` authentication here

Comment: but I am not using it

Comment: I will remove it as It doesn't do anything

Comment: Integrate authentication within your application, it will become much easier

Comment: but I need to login in with three different users {Student, Teacher, and Admin}

Comment: How to achieve this ??

Comment: yes integrate all in firebase authentication, and in your database add a field called userType and assign it to either student or teacher or admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216476/discussion-between-omar-developer-and-peter-haddad).